# magnolia: How to customize STK

Tags: magnolia

I spent alot of time to customize magnolia STK but it does not work.

I have included STK dependency in the pom.xml of an empty project as follow:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I run my empty webapp with tomcat and can build some pages with customized basic templates. STK is also available in my 
webapp see [image: screenshot]

my question is: How to build page with STK?  How to customize/use STK in my project?

Answer (score 1):

What is it that you want to customise that doesn't work? Perhaps you are trying to change the wrong things?
With STK you get set of page and component templates. You can either work with them out of the box if the structure of html generated by them works for you. In this case you would be only restyling components by changing theme (css, js, images). Or if basic html doesn't work for you , you can write your own ftl/jsp template scripts to replace original ones to generate whatever html for page structure you need (or same for the components).

If you want to make new components available in given area of page template, you can either register (add) the name of the component in stk:/site-configuration/templates/prototype/areas/ or directly under given page area configuration.

If you are planning to do extensive modifications to default STK templates, you will find it beneficial in long run to not change things directly under STK templates, but to build your own template structure (pages, components) that would be just extending those provided by STK and override only parts of configuration that you need to change. To have template extend another template just add "extends" property and set it's value to point to node you want to extend (both relative and absolute path works).

HTH,
Jan